# backbone.js: Model event that fires when setting attributes to existing values?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

In backbone.js, I'm noticing that the `change` and `all` events on a `Model` do not fire if you `set` the Model's attributes to its existing attributes.

For example, if I set up the following events:

```
 ActiveUser.bind('change', this.displayActiveUser, this);
 ActiveUser.bind('all', this.displayActiveUserAll, this);
```

And then I manually set the value of ActiveUser to the empty string:

```
ActiveUser.set({ text : '' });
```

The events fire **if and only if `ActiveUser.text` is not already set to the empty string**.

This is reasonable behaviour. However, is there an event I can use that will fire even if the value being set is the existing value?

Update: I don't see anything in the official Backbone.js [list of events](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#FAQ-events). Hmm.

Comment: You can always manually run `ActiveUser.trigger('change')`

Comment: Thanks - that's what I'll do!

Comment: I added my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can always trigger the change event manually with `ActiveUser.trigger('change');`.

Answer (score 3):

Trigger change event manually as abraham said

```
MyModel.trigger('change')
```

So its possible to trigger change event manually but it will not work well in some cases. Consider the case when your render method takes properties from model and your model is empty initially, so if your code sets something on model and straight after that line you say `MyView.render()` or `MyModel.trigger('change')` then what happens your render method might be faster and will not even take newly set properties.

Quick hacky alternative could be each time you set something, generate random number along and pass it to model:

```
MyModel.set({myProperty:something,rand:Math.random()});
```

or

```
MyModel.set({myProperty:something,t:(new Date).getTime()});
```

So in this case you are sure that model will always fire change event just because something changes, but it is hacky and if you have a lot going on then your app will become random number calculator.

Alternatively go with Peter Lyons method.

Comment: The hacky alternative surely works, but a straight forward trigger is much more obvious than that.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you need a Backbone.Model subclass that is a parent class of any of your own Model classes that want this behavior. Override the `set` method something along these lines. The logic to only fire events on changes is coded into `Backbone.Model.set` in a way that doesn't easily support adding a new option.

(...excerpt...)

```
set: function(key, value, options) {
    //Handle both "key", value and {key: value} -style arguments.
    if (_.isObject(key) || key == null) {
        options = value;
    }
    this.change(options); //This fires the event
    Backbone.Model.prototype.set.apply(this, arguments);//Trigger normal behavior as well
```